# How to be made aware of incoming emails on GMail without frequent polling?

Tags: java, android, oauth, gmail, gmail-imap

If I am developing an Android application, what is the most feasible way to get near real-time notifications about an incoming email? Is there a push-like mechanism, or can I hold my IMAP connection for a long time, or do I use IDLE command?
Consider that user is authorized to use GMail services via OAuth and I don't want to poll IMAP server madly.

Update:

- I'm not using the phone's configured-in Google account. There is another account set up using OAuth.
- I'm using [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) to connect to IMAP/SMTP in my app. It's a bare-bone library for IMAP, but I can perhaps modify it to add IMAP commands/extensions.

Comment: Is it an option to set up a server that polls and then pushes using for example GCM to the devices?

Comment: Polling is out.  Server-side solution is out.  The phones native email tools are out.  Have you considered quantum computing?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but here is my criteria: 1- No external dependency that can fail the app (except mail server itself) 2- No storing user's data or sending it to somewhere else (users don't feel comfortable if a server-side component they can't see and control can read their mailbox. The communications of the app they have can be controlled/restricted by them.) 3- No locking to GMail or any other mail server (how about an Android user whose primary email is on Yahoo?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IMAP does natively provide any sort of push notifications and the [Google extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions) don't either, you have to implement it yourself.

One way is to use `IDLE` requests, which is still a cheap way to do polling. Of course, you can't expect your app to be running all the time, so you need to use a background service. An 'always-on' service is however an anti-pattern on Android and will drain the battery quickly and likely get you many 1-stars. Additionally the system may decide to kill it at any time. The other alternative is to use `AlarmManager` to start the service periodically, but starting it every couple of seconds or so is just as bad. So you are basically back to square one: polling.

The other way is to get push notifications using GCM or a similar service. This does require you to have a server, and the server needs to have the authentication info for the user (which might be a problem), but there are no real constraints concerning keeping open connections and sending IDLEs each second, etc. On the Android side, if you want to implement push yourself, you need to keep an open socket to get notifications. This is not very easy to do if you are not a system app (see above), so that leaves GCM. The connection it uses is manged by the system (Google Services framework), it can do things a regular app cannot, and you basically get it for free, since it's already there. It receives small pieces of data when there is something to do, called 'tickles'. Those in turn trigger broadcasts, Google Play updates, etc.

So, take your pick. Or just give up, register the account and use GMail and its labels [Android API](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a closer look into the options you talked about. Can you please elaborate the "connection('trickle')" part a little more?

Comment: I actually meant 'tickle'. See updated answer, but it's basically a always open (when possible) TCP connection. It's a Google proprietary extension though, so no real documentation on the actual implementation.

Comment: I'd recommend not trying to implement your own push service.  In our experience, U.S. carriers can interfere with server-initiated socket-based communication via firewalls.  Device IPs are also very dynamic on 3G, 4G, WiFi, and you need to keep track of these changes.

Comment: Looks like I'll go ahead with IDLE (or GCM, depending on the authentication mechanism). As a user myself I don't feel comfortable giving permission to a web service to read my inbox.

Answer (score 3):

You can register a [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) with GMail, anytime something changes in GMail, the observer will be called.

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls"), true, myContentObserver );
```

Override `onChange` in your ContentObserver to do stuff when something in GMail changes.

Comment: This is not an option, as I don't work with the phone's default account.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out Google Cloud Messaging (GCM):

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html

My understanding is that this works without requiring the user's Google account, and lets you handle authentication.

See a tutorial here:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/implementing-googles-cloud-to-device-messaging/428

You would need additional server-side code running to do this though.

Comment: This is good, but I'd rather not involve a server-side component to keep things simple.